# Measure time from code execution to bluetooth low energy transmission on iPhone using intruments

Tags: xcode, instruments, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to measure how long it takes before my code executes a transfer call until the actual packets is sent over the air. 
Is this possible using the XCode developer tool "Instruments" or is it best to look for timestamps in my code somewhere?

All help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have used Packet Analyzer to debug traces over the air (http://www.fte.com/). But it's a very expensive tool.

Otherwise, you won't get a precise measurement. You have no idea, what delays could hardware create.

Although it would be fun to have a look. Set connection intervals of your tag and then check with logging timestamp if the delta you get is similar to delta you set.